# django - user profile is used as foreign key in another model. how to show the logged in user in the form?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a form to upload files and am using a foreignkey to route the files to a specific folder the user is grouped under. Now in my upload form the users are listed in a dropdown menu. Could someone help me to show only the current logged in user name

This is my models.py for the uplaod form

```py
class uploadmeta(models.Model):

    path = models.ForeignKey(Metadataform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Username')

    tar_gif = models.FileField(upload_to=nice_user_folder_upload, verbose_name="Dataset") # validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['tar', 'zip'])]


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('file_list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Assigned_Group= models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=Group_choices, default='Please Select')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```py
class uploadmetaform(forms.ModelForm):
        count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id #To know the id of latest object
        data  = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count) #return the queryset with only latest object
        path  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data, initial=0, label='Meta ID')


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(uploadmetaform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id
            data = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count)
            self.fields['path'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data, initial=0, label='Meta ID')


        class Meta:
            model = uploadmeta
            fields = ['path', 'user_profile','tar_gif',]
```

```py
def uploaddata(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

                 if request.method == 'POST':
                        uploadmetaform(request=request)
                        form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES, request=request)
                        if form.is_valid():
                                form.save()

                                return redirect('file_list')
                else:
                        form = uploadmetaform()
                return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                        'form': form
                })
        else:
                return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access logged in user as `request.user` so if you want username you can do `request.user.username` now if you want it in form you can pass a keyword argument like this 
`uploadmetaform(request=request)` and in you form you can access it

```
class uploadmetaform(forms.ModelForm):
        count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id #To know the id of latest object
        data  = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count) #return the queryset with only latest object
        path  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data, initial=0, label='Meta ID')
        username=forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(uploadmetaform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        username=kwargs.get("request").user.username
        self.fields['username'] = username
        count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id
        data = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count)
        self.fields['path'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data, initial=0, label='Meta ID')
```

or in a django template if user is authenticated you can do `{{ user.get_username }}`

Comment: it gives me this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'User' at this line username=kwargs.get("request").user.username

Comment: i did not understand this part --  uploadmetaform(request=request). where do i add this? replace something?

Comment: You pass it while creating your form in view `uploadmetaform(request=request)`

Comment: I am getting the same error -   

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: are you sure you are passint this ` uploadmetaform(request=request)`

Comment: i have added the views to my question, i did the (request=request)

Comment: not in `def uploaddata(request=request):`
 you did it wrong pass it in `uploadmetaform(request=request)` and                         `form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES,request=request)`

Comment: i have edited my question, please check. if i am still not right please specify  in views,py or forms.py...

Comment: you again missed it here                         `form = uploadmetaform()` try                         `form = uploadmetaform(request=request)`

Comment: if i do that i am getting a new error: 'uploadmetaform' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: I have edited the answer super should be called above

Comment: error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Comment: cant help without traceback

Comment: i guess its something to do in this part    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username in the userProfile class

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there is any direct way to do this or not but you can always pass user object to the form(in your case logged in user)
This may help!

```
form = uploadmetadata(**{'user':request.user})
```

In this way you can pass the user object to your django form.
This may help!